# How to Create Pin Pattern Password using xamarin form?

Tags: design-patterns, xamarin, passwords

I am trying to create a pin pattern password screen. I was wondering what is the best way to develop this using Xamarin forms. I have looked into the documentation , but did not help me. Can this be done using one of the Gesture event? Any pointers highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'd say use a pan gesture (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pan/) to track the selection. You can draw lines with `BoxView` using a specific `WidthRequest` or `HeightRequest`, and there is a rotation property for each axis to created diagonal lines. I think a `GridLayout`, `AbsoluteLayout`, or `RelativeLayout` would allow the necessary layering. A grid might be the easiest to use for this, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

just needed the same thing for a project. Take a look at my solution: http://software.fauland.cc/?p=5619

Note: I didn't implement the lines since it was not neccessary for the customer. Maybe I'll add it in the future.